# Is it possible to give user input name to a table that is being created in sql with the help of python interface?

Tags: mysql-python

I am trying to do a project which involves the creating of a new table with a user input name, but it does not work. I hope the given information is enough.

This is what I tried:

```py
import mysql.connector as myc

db=myc.connect(host='localhost',database='xyz',user='root',passwd='root')
mc=db.cursor()

name=input("name=")` 

x=("CREATE TABLE %s (S_NO VARCHAR(100),CONSULTATION_REASON VARCHAR(100),CONSULTED_DOCTOR VARCHAR(100),
FEES VARCHAR(100))")` 

mc.execute(x,name)
db.commit
```

and it gives this error:

> error:::mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s (S_NO VARCHAR(100), CONSULTATION_REASON VARCHAR(100), CONSULTED_DOCTOR VARCHAR(' at line 1:::

I would really appreciate any answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
import mysql.connector as myc
db=myc.connect(host='localhost',database='xyz',user='root',passwd='root')
mc=db.cursor()
name=input("name=")
x=("CREATE TABLE "+name+" (S_NO VARCHAR(100),CONSULTATION_REASON 
VARCHAR(100),CONSULTED_DOCTOR VARCHAR(100), FEES VARCHAR(100))")
mc.execute(x,name)
db.commit
```

Comment: What was wrong with the original code? What did you change? Why does that resolve it?

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked. I just needed to remove the "mc.execute(x,name)" part and add the mc.execute to this part ""("CREATE TABLE "+name+" (S_NO VARCHAR(100),CONSULTATION_REASON ....."". THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR THE QUICK HELP.highly appreciated

Comment: @underscore_d This is an error sending parameters and I changed it and @G Sree said it works
Why do you say it is no different from the original code?

Comment: @shahedmahmoudi I did not say "it is no different". I asked **how** it was different. A good answer would not just dump altered code, but also explain how/why it had been altered. That was my point. And it seems someone else agreed, since I did not downvote, but they did.

Comment: @underscore_d you can see this linke 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html
 you have two option for parametr in my sql,  '+' or with '@'  I am not mysql developer but I have a littel knowlage about that